# Automatic crash on Angular universal project on server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

In the Angular universal project. After a while on the server, the site automatically crashes and the server needs to be restarted.

These errors are in the log.

This has happened twice in the last month.

There are too many "Converting circular structure to JSON" errors in the log file.

```
(node:24572) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'XMLHttpRequest'
|     property 'upload' -> object with constructor 'XMLHttpRequestUpload'
--- property '_request' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at readableObjectToString (D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1495120)
at resolvePromise (D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1498869)
at resolvePromise (D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1497774)
at D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1500424
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1489452)
at Object.onInvokeTask (D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1984912)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1489342)
at Zone.runTask (D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1482017)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (D:\Inetpub\vhosts\ipdemy.ir\httpdocs\main.js:1:1493060) {
rejection: HttpErrorResponse {
headers: HttpHeaders {
  normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
  lazyUpdate: null,
  headers: Map(0) {}
},
status: 0,
statusText: 'Unknown Error',
url: 'https://www.systemapi.ipdemy.ir/api/global/Bootstrapper',
ok: false,
name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
message: 'Http failure response for https://www.systemapi.ipdemy.ir/api/global/Bootstrapper: 0 Unknown Error',
error: ProgressEvent {
  type: 'error',
  target: [XMLHttpRequest],
  currentTarget: [XMLHttpRequest],
  lengthComputable: false,
  loaded: 0,
  total: 0
}
},
```

Comment: Do you config SSL correctly? I mean this may because of free SSL or incorrectly SSL config.

Comment: This is probably due to TransferState trying to serialize a circular response object. You need to identify which request is cauqing the issu to solve this

Comment: I do not have TransferState in my project. This error has occurred overtime on the bootstrapper endpoint @David